# Appending a value to the Aurelia router config.title

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I want to set a base title value for my Aurelia application and then append a value to it based on the route that is active.

My router configuration is:

```
export class App {
    configureRouter(config, router) {
        config.title = 'Brandon Taylor | Web Developer | Graphic Designer';
        config.map([
            . . .
            { route: 'work', name: 'work', moduleId: 'work', nav: true, title: ' | work' },
            . . .
        ]);

        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

Aurelia wants to append the `title` navigation parameter to the *beginning* of the `config.title`, but I would like it at the *end*.

I've tried doing an override in the view model:

```
export class Work {
    activate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction) {
        routeConfig.navModel.router.title += ' | work';
    };
}
```

but this results in:

```
Brandon Taylor | Web Developer | Graphic Designer | work | work | work ...
```

on each routing request. What am I doing wrong? or how can I append the route `title` attribute to the *end* of the `config.title` instead of the beginning?

Comment: The better question is why is activate being called three times.

Comment: @AshleyGrant is there another callback I should be using? I'm just getting started with Aurelia. Thanks.

Comment: No, you're looking in the right place. However, there is a bigger issue if a route is being activated multiple times. To start, drop a breakpoint in your activate callback and see whats happening and why.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis what am I looking for in regards to why `activate()` would be called multiple times? If I `console.log('activate called');` inside the method itself, and navigate to the route, nav away and nav back, I see multiple log statements.

Comment: hard to say without some code to look at. did you ask someone in the gitter channel? https://gitter.im/Aurelia/Discuss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Jeremy Danyow.

What I ended up with was:

```
import {NavigationContext} from 'aurelia-router';

NavigationContext.prototype.standardBuildTitle = NavigationContext.prototype.buildTitle;

function buildTitle(separator=' | ') {
    var titleValues = this.standardBuildTitle(separator).split(separator),
        routeTitle = titleValues[0],
        configTitle = titleValues.slice(1);
    configTitle.push(routeTitle);
    return configTitle.join(separator);
}

NavigationContext.prototype.buildTitle = buildTitle;
```

The reason being that given:

```
config.title = 'Brandon Taylor | Web Developer | Graphic Designer'
```

and calling:

```
return standardTitle.split(separator).reverse().join(separator);
```

results in:

```
Graphic Designer | Web Developer | Brandon Taylor | about
```

instead of:

```
Brandon Taylor | Web Developer | Graphic Designer | about
```

Answer (score 5):

Aurelia's standard title logic prepends the route title to the outer route/router's title.  For example, in the skeleton-navigation app, the application router's title is Aurelia.  The github users route's title is prepended to the router title producing `Github Users | Aurelia`.  If you were to navigate to the child router page, the title updates to `Welcome | Child Router | Aurelia`.
[image: title]

If I understand the question correctly, you would like this logic reversed.  The desired result in this example would be `Aurelia | Child Router | Welcome`.

The title building logic resides in [`NavigationContext`](https://github.com/aurelia/router/blob/master/src/navigation-context.js) class's `buildTitle` method.

You can override this method by adding the following to your main.js:

```js
// import the NavigationContext class.  It contains the method that
// builds the title.
import {NavigationContext} from 'aurelia-router';

// rename the standard "buildTitle" method.
NavigationContext.prototype.standardBuildTitle = NavigationContext.prototype.buildTitle;

// replace the standard "buildTitle" method with a version that
// reverses the order of the title parts.
function buildTitle(separator = ' | ') {
  let standardTitle = this.standardBuildTitle(separator);
  return standardTitle.split(separator).reverse().join(separator);
}
NavigationContext.prototype.buildTitle = buildTitle;
```

The end result looks like this:
[image: result]

Comment: Very close! The order of the words of the config title get reversed. See my answer.

Comment: This is now in in NavigationInstruction and the method is _buildTitle: https://github.com/aurelia/router/blob/master/src/navigation-instruction.js#L226

Comment: Are you sure that `_buildTitle` is intended for public use? The [API](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/router/1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/doc/api/class/NavigationInstruction) doesn't mention it.

Comment: You can just use https://aurelia.io/docs/routing/configuration#internationalizing-titles

Answer (score 0):

I know that the code above is a ~dirty~ workaround, but maybe can help you until you get a beautiful way to get what you want from Aurelia support.

Couldn't you do:

```
export class App {
    configureRouter(config, router) {
        const title = 'Brandon Taylor | Web Developer | Graphic Designer';
        config.title = '';
        var configMap = [
            . . .
            { route: 'work', name: 'work', moduleId: 'work', nav: true, title: ' | work' },
            . . .
        ];
        configMap.forEach(item => item.title = title + item.title);

        config.map(configMap);    
        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

Comment: Clever :) This works great for static titles, but not with dynamic values in views.