# how to not show parent | child routes on document title

Tags: aurelia

Is there any way to configure the router to stop showing parent | child routes at the document title? Note that the child routes need to be configured with a title string and 'nav: true' because they are displayed in a nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

While this looks very dirty, this should be possible

```
activate(params, route, navigationInstruction) { // I neglected to include the final navigationInstruction parameter in earlier posts
  route.navModel.setTitle('New Title');
}
```

Or possible overriding the buildTitle, this [enhancement](https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/218#) refers to it but it's still open.

and [Appending a value to the Aurelia router config.title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802219/appending-a-value-to-the-aurelia-router-config-title) looks like it might be close to the answer you're looking for.